# 21.04 Prevent sleep while sharing media (UPnP/DLNA)

Tags: suspend, power-management, file-sharing, dlna, upnp

21.04 has built in support for sharing media using UPnP (aka DLNA) in Settings > Share. If the machine goes to sleep while someone accesses this media the stream is broken for the client when e.g. watching a video.

**Is there an option to prevent the system from going to sleep while media is accessed?** I found nothing in the power management panel.

Comment: It would be better to prevent it to go to sleep at all.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is enable "wake on lan"
As long as there is network requests to your host, it will stay awake. Additionally, if someone tries to access you machine while asleep, it will come out of sleep mode and serve the files requested.
External link
https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Set_up_Wake-on-LAN_for_Ubuntu
For WLAN, have a look at

https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/wake-on-wlan

Comment: It is? And that will work over WiFi?

Comment: @Andreas No....

Comment: Ubuntu supports wlan as well
https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/wake-on-wlan